# Non-existent column when using SQLite and MySQL with Elixir but not when used separately

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, qgis, python-elixir

In my plugin for Qgis  I have to use two databases, SQLite and MySQL at the moment, for interfacing with them I use Elixir 0.7.1 and SqlAlchemy 0.7.4. When I only used SQLite, everything was fine, recently I added the module for MySQL, as far I test them separately, they work nicely, but when I put all together I got this from qgis :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 164, in startPlugin
plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
File "/home/giuseppe/.qgis/python/plugins/mmasgis/__init__.py", line 37, in classFactory
return mmasgis(iface)
File "/home/giuseppe/.qgis/python/plugins/mmasgis/mmasgis.py", line 84, in __init__
self.selectionList=Lista()
File "/home/giuseppe/.qgis/python/plugins/mmasgis/lista.py", line 7, in __init__
self.util=utility([],0)
File "/home/giuseppe/.qgis/python/plugins/mmasgis/utility.py", line 266, in __init__
initDB()
File "/home/giuseppe/.qgis/python/plugins/mmasgis/mysqlEntities.py", line 7, in initDB
setup_all()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/elixir/__init__.py", line 94, in setup_all
setup_entities(entities)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/elixir/entity.py", line 951, in setup_entities
method()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/elixir/entity.py", line 240, in setup_relkeys
self.call_builders('create_non_pk_cols')
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/elixir/entity.py", line 481, in call_builders
getattr(builder, what)()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/elixir/fields.py", line 155, in create_non_pk_cols
self.create_col()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/elixir/fields.py", line 160, in create_col
self.add_table_column(self.column)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/elixir/properties.py", line 84, in add_table_column
self.entity._descriptor.add_column(column)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/elixir/entity.py", line 493, in add_column
(col.key, self.entity.__name__))
Exception: Column 'nome' already exist in 'Regione' ! 

Versione Python:
2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:29:37) 
[GCC 4.6.1]


Versione di QGIS:
1.9.90-Alpha Alpha, exported

Percorso Python: ['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/giuseppe/.qgis/python', '/home       /giuseppe/.qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyshp-1.1.4-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.4-py2.7-linux-i686.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Numeric', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/ubuntuone-dev-tools', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/libubuntuone', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-file-storage-api', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools', '/home/giuseppe/Documenti/doc/progetti/mmasgis/gianluca/ProgettoGIS', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/', '/home/giuseppe/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/']
```

this is my entities module for SQLite: http://pastebin.com/ya4q9En1
this is the enties module for MySQL: http://pastebin.com/3NypygV4

Can you help me to understand where my mistake is?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Elixir. Nowadays, SQLAlchemy's built-in declarative has most of its features and you'll get (much) better support than for Elixir.

Answer (score 0):

i translated my application from elixir to sqlalchemy, but I still get the same error message, I begin to think that the problem is not in my code, but in sqlite db this would not be the first time for me  that the db created by elixir is faulty.